# sync iCloud manually

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, icloud, ios5

I am working on data management application in iphone , In the app I am saving set of data using core data(like name address,contact detail etc...).

Now i want to sync existing data to iCloud only if user want to sync, and on other side i want to import all data which is on iCloud only if user wants else app should work well with local app data.So how could i complete such manually import export operation on iCloud?

some thing menu like "sync from iCloud" and "sync to iCloud"

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very general.

As first step I recommend you take a look at the following WWDC session videos:

1. WWDC2012: Session 209 - **iCloud Storage Overview**
2. WWDC2012: Session 227 - **Using iCloud with Core Data**
3. WWDC2011: Session 116 - **Storing Documents in iCloud Using iOS5** (for brief glimpse into
   UIManagedDocument).